# Postgres JSON NULL not activating parameter default

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL 14, unspecified arguments in a JSON string are interfering with parameter defaults in function calls despite appearing to be NULL.

I believe **tst := j::json->>'tst';** is filling tst with a pseudo-null value.

Have I missed something simple?  I thought about coalescing into declared variables in testNull but it feels messy and I feel like there must be a more elegant approach.

```
create or replace function testNull(test varchar, tst int default 1) returns int
language plpgsql as $$
declare
begin 
    
    raise notice '%', tst;
    
    return tst;
end; $$;

----------------------------

create or replace function testNulljson(j varchar) returns int
language plpgsql as $$
declare
    test varchar;
    tst int;
begin 
    
    raise notice '%', tst;
    
    test := j::json->>'test';
    tst := j::json->>'tst';
    return testNull(test, tst);

end; $$;

----------------------------

select testNull('testValue');  -- returns 1

select testNulljson('{"test":"testValue"}'); -- returns null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-default.html

> A column can be assigned a default value. When a new row is created
> and no values are specified for some of the columns, those columns
> will be filled with their respective default values.

There is a difference:
a. `select * from public.testNull('testValue', NULL);`
b. `select * from public.testNull('testValue' );`
a will return `NULL`, b will return `1`;

When you call `select testNulljson('{"test":"testValue"}');`  You finally is calling `select * from public.testNull('testValue', NULL);` It will return Null.

when you call `select testNull('testValue');  -- returns 1` You didn't mention `tst` input argument, it will replaced by 1 therefore return 1.